# Error with prysm beacon-chain with testnet pyrmont

Tags: ethereum, ether, hyperledger-besu

I am trying to run a beacon-chain for Ethereum2.0 in the pyrmont testnet with Prysm and Besu.

I run the ETH1 node with the command :

```
besu --network=goerli --data-path=/root/goerliData --rpc-http-enabled
```

This command is working and download the entire blockchain, then run properly.

But when I launch :

```
./prysm.sh beacon-chain --http-web3provider=localhost:8545 --pyrmont
```

I get :

```
Verified /root/prysm/dist/beacon-chain-v1.0.0-beta.3-linux-amd64 has been signed by Prysmatic Labs.
Starting Prysm beacon-chain --http-web3provider=localhost:8545 --pyrmont
[2020-11-18 14:03:06]  WARN flags: Running on Pyrmont Testnet
[2020-11-18 14:03:06]  INFO flags: Using "max_cover" strategy on attestation aggregation
[2020-11-18 14:03:06]  INFO node: Checking DB database-path=/root/.eth2/beaconchaindata
[2020-11-18 14:03:08] ERROR main: database contract is xxxxxxxxxxxx3fdc but tried to run with xxxxxxxxxxxx6a8c
```

I tried to delete the previous data folder `/root/goerliData` and re-download the blockchain but  nothing changed...

Why does the database contract didn't change and what should I do ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that you have an existing database for another network, probably medalla.

Try starting your beacon node with the flag `--clear-db` next time, and you'll see it the error disappear and start syncing Pyrmont.